# How to add two images side by side dynamically

Tags: android, imageview, dynamically-generated

I am generating image view dynamically. That is in Asysntask.

In PostExecute Method, I am inflating this layout :

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/imageLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="abcd"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnCapturePicture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/imageview"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageLabel"

  />
```

And in code :

```
    (build_types.getJSONObject(i).getString("name").equals("Image")) {



                    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View imageview = inflater.inflate(
    R.layout.imagecapture, null);

                    final ImageView imgPreview = (ImageView) imageview
                            .findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
                    final TextView imageText = (TextView) imageview.findViewById(R.id.imageLabel);

                    imageText.setText(build_types.getJSONObject(i).getString("label"));
                    imgPreview.setId(Integer.parseInt(build_types
                            .getJSONObject(i).getString("id")));

                    if (type == 6) {
                         if(image==1){
                            image=0;
                         }
                        else{
                            image++;
                            System.out.println("Inside 2 consequetive images::");

                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            //imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                            System.out.println("Image Count Id::"+imgPreview.getId());
                            System.out.println("ImageID Flag::"+imagIdFlag);

                        //  imageParams.setLayoutDirection(Layout.DIR_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
                            imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                            imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,imgPreview.getId());

                            imgPreview.setLayoutParams(imageParams);



                        }


                    }
                    rv.addView(imageview);

                    type = 6;
```

I am getting exact count when I have to keep images side by side by setting image flag. However images appear one below another.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that "rv" is a LinearLayout with the orientation set to horizontal and just inflate your views and add into it.

Comment: I cants do this. because i am inflating so many components . For it I have to keep layout orientation vertical.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type of Layout is `"rv"` in `rv.addView(imageview);`, but it's probably a `vertical` oriented `LinearLayout`. Just set the orientation of this `Layout` to `horizontal`.

Comment: rv is main Linear layout where I am adding all the components.

Comment: OK ! what you should do then is set an empty horizontal LinearLayout in this main Linear. Give it an id, and add your inflated view in this one :)